# Role isn't evaluated but S3 bucket policy is

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

### End goal

I'm using cognito identity pools to give users permission to read an S3 bucket. The idea is that each user has a "folder" (prefix) that they can read and they shouldn't be able to read anyone elses folder.

### General design

The way I have this plumbed up is:

- Users sign in via a cognito user pool (this works)
- They use the cognito identity pool to assume a role (after checking the s3 access logs, I also think this works)
- They hit the s3 endpoint

Now, **the s3 bucket has policy and the role also has policy** (which is below). **The problem is only the s3 policy is being evaluated.**

### Details

#### Role

The role is called "S3Stuff"

Role permissions

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket>",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": "${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Role trust relationship

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Federated": "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": "us-east-1:<GUID>"
                },
                "StringLike": {
                    "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": "authenticated"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

#### S3 Bucket Policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::720911909616:role/S3Stuff"
            },
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket>"
        }
    ]
}
```

#### What happens

With the above S3 configuration, when I log into cognito as a user, I can list the entire contents of the bucket. When I add a condition to the s3 bucket policy (like below) it works correctly (ie I can list the part of the bucket I should be able to and can't access what I couldn't be able to). Also before I put the s3 policy on it was denying me access.

Condition

```
"Condition": {
    "StringLike": {
        "s3:prefix": "${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"
    }
}
```

To be clear **I know I *can* just throw everything into the s3 policy but I want to know what's going on and *why.***

**Why is the policy in the role being bypassed**

Comment: Does the IAM principal that is setting all of this up have either a superset of the S3 permissions being passed here or have iam:PassRole permission for the S3Stuff role? I'm assuming so, but just checking per the [RBAC docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/role-based-access-control.html).

Comment: My IAM user has `Action: "*"` and `Resource: "*"` for everything in us-east-1

Comment: You should _not_ be using a Bucket Policy. All necessary permissions should be granted via the role, so there is no need to use a Bucket Policy. Your Bucket Policy shown above is granting them too much permission.

Comment: I thought that the permissions to access a bucket (for a role) is the most restrictive union of bucket policy and role policy. This would imply that if I don't have any bucket policy I can't access the bucket (since it's default deny). Furthermore, if I don't include the bucket policy I can't access any part of the bucket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This picture is key. I got it from "Deep Dive with Security: AWS Identity and Access Management" on the AWS Learning thing.

[image: this shows in which order policy is evaluated. First is AWS Organization, then Resource based, then Permission Boundaries, then Session Policy, and finally Identity-based. Resource based policy can approve immediately]

I was [mislead](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/iam-policies-and-bucket-policies-and-acls-oh-my-controlling-access-to-s3-resources/) into thinking that the policy that applies to a request is the "least-privilege union" of all the policies. This is very close to being right but it is *untrue*.

1. All policies are parsed.
2. If there is an explicit deny ("Effect": "Deny") then the whole thing is denied.
3. If there isn't an explicit deny then it starts looking for implicit denies (this is when the policy doesn't have an "Effect": "Allow" clause that lets me do a thing). *EXCEPT* the resource based policies let you short circuit the search for implicit denies. If a resource explicitly allows you then you skip: permission boundaries, session policy, and identity policy (which includes roles and IAM).

**If you have a resource based policy that approves an action the role policies will only have an effect if there is an explicit deny.**

Concerning the part where I said that before I put the S3 policy on I was being denied access, It's probably because of the cognito aud. I was using the wrong aud for a while (the cognito aud being refereed to comes from cognito-identity pools ***not*** cognito user pools just in case anyone was curious) and eventually figured it out and used the right one. I must have started testing s3 policy before changing the aud to the right thing.

Comment: Unfortunately that interesting diagram is pretty much false. :)
Just a test: create a user policy that allows access to a specific bucket.
Lo and behold: ALL access to public buckets even in other accounts is denied.